# Show that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}$ doesn't exists.(by $\epsilon-\delta$ definition)

Tags: limits

This is my exercise problem:
To prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}$ doesn't exist using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

> My attempt

I am trying to show that the left hand and right hand limit exsts but of different values and hence the limit doesn't exist.
Let, $f(x)=\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}$

Step 1.
To Show, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}=0.$
Let $\epsilon>0.$ We have to show that $\exists \  \delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $0<x<\delta$.
Now, $|f(x)|=|\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}|=\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}<\epsilon \Longrightarrow x<\frac{1}{log(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1)}$ for $0<\epsilon<1$.
Therefore, when we take $0<\epsilon<1$ we choose $\delta=\frac{1}{log(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1)}$.
(but here my question ...what if  $log(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1)<0$...?? Then this $\delta$ no more positive...!!)
When $\epsilon \ge1,$
 $|f(x)|=|\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}|=\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}<\epsilon \Longrightarrow e^{1/x}>1/\epsilon-1$ and this is true for all $x.$ Hence all $\delta>0$ works here.
Then, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}=0.$ (proved)

Step 2.
Now to show, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0-}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}+1}=1.$
We have to find a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$ for all $-\delta<x<0$.
here, $|f(x)-1|=\frac{1}{1+e^{-1/x}}<\epsilon \Longrightarrow e^{1/x}>\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}.$

Now I cannot choose the $\delta$ here.....
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to calculate the best possible value for $\delta$. Here's  a **hint**:

If $\;0<\mathrm e^{\tfrac1x}<\varepsilon$, then
$\quad1-\varepsilon<\dfrac1{1+\varepsilon} <f(x)< 1$.